# Adding a nuget package to C++ project gives LNK2001 error when building

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, lnk2001

I have a C++ Visual Studio 2015 project that uses cpprestsdk. I added the nuget package for cpprest in Visual Studio using Tools/Nuget Package Manager. I have no error on include files from cpprest and they are recognized by Visual Studio, the problem is that when I try to build my project I get a lot of LNK2001 errors such as this one:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl utility::conversions::to_string_t(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &&)" (?to_string_t@conversions@utility@@YA?AV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@$$QEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@@Z) check-cpprest-nug   D:\Work\visual-projects\check-cpprest-nug\check-cpprest-nug\check-cpprest-nug.obj   1
```

I thought that the linkage was automatic following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) which is originally for C# but I can't find anything specific to C++.

Am I missing any steps in the Project Properties?

** Edit **

I'm adding a piece of code to give more context but I think the problem is either linkage related or due to project configurations. The project works just fine when cpprest is statically linked and not linked using nuget.

```
std::ostringstream msg;

    utility::string_t address(U("https://*** --- ***"));
    
    http::uri uri = http::uri(address);

    http::client::http_client req(uri);

    try
    {
        auto response = req.request(http::methods::GET).get();

        auto status = response.status_code();

        if (status != http::status_codes::OK)
        {
            msg << "COUNTER PARTY LOOKUP :: Http Request could not be completed successfully with error code: " << status << "\n";

            throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
        }

        json::value obj = response.extract_json().get();

        std::cout << utility::conversions::to_utf8string( obj.serialize() )<< std::endl;

    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {

        msg << "COUNTER PARTY LOOKUP :: Problem opening connection. Try again later." << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: can you show a code, but as i remember i've got this error, when i pass `std::string` to any functions in `cpprestsdk`, where `std::wstring` is used, or if you try to pass raw `const char *`, if so, solution is really easy. Instead typing `"Hello world"`, type: `L"Hello world"`

Comment: Could you share a piece of code for us to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Also, what is the nuget specific name?

Comment: Hi Mahshid, any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue and let us know if it helps. And it will help us give you better support.

Comment: Hi I added some code. The project builds just fine when cpprest is statically linked I just can't get it to build with nuget. Also I'm obliged to use my company's cpprest nuget package. @PerryQian-MSFT

Comment: @MahshidKhezriNejad, try to add `_NO_ASYNCRTIMP;_NO_PPLXIMP` by project `Properties`-->`C/C++`-->'Preprocessor'-->add `_NO_ASYNCRTIMP;_NO_PPLXIMP` into `Preprocessor Definitions`. Then enter Linker-->Input--> add `bcrypt.lib` and `winhttp.lib` into `Additional Dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have your code and cannot trace the specific point of your issue, this is my suggestion

**Suggestion**

You should statically connect to `cpprestsdk`,  as for me, I should add `_NO_ASYNCRTIMP` in the preprocess and then add `bcrypt.lib` and `winhttp.lib` into the linker of my project.

**To realize all of these**, you should install a nuget package called [cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-static](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-static/) instead.

This package will add these points into your project automatically when you install it.

**Remember** to include these header files:

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
```

**Note**: you should use `Debug/Release` Configuration and `win32/x64` platform. Keep the **Platform Toolset** to `Visual Studio 2015 v140`.

**Besides**, if it does not work for your issue, I suggest you could share your code with us so that we can troubleshoot the issue more quickly.